# How to convert Future[Seq[A]] into Map[String, Seq[A]]?

Tags: scala

I have a function which return a Future[Seq[A]]

```
def foo(x:String): Future[Seq[A]]
```

Then how can I convert it into a Map[String, Seq[A]] ?

This is What I have tried

```
foo(x).map { e =>
(ResponseHeader.Ok, e.groupBy(_.use).mapValues(???))
}
```

*EDIT :
What I want to achieve is to group by my Seq based on 1 of its column as the key, and convert it into a `Map[key, Seq[A]]`.
I tried to group by it, but I dont know what to put inside the `mapValues`

Comment: Apart from a missing `)` this code looks OK. Is it the grouping code that is causing problems, or the fact that the result is in a `Future`?

Comment: I will edit my question again. the missing of `)` was only a typo when I copied it to here. I will add it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mapValues` call is not required, the `groupBy` will give you what you want:

```
val e: Seq[A] = ???
val map: Map[String, Seq[A]] = e.groupBy(_.use)

val res: Future[(Int, Map[String, Seq[A]])] =
  foo("").map { e =>
    (ResponseHeader.Ok, e.groupBy(_.use))
  }
```